# Alternate domain in XMLhttprequest?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data, form-data

I have some code I'm using to upload a file async - it works great:

---

```
var form = document.getElementById('form-id');

var formData = new FormData(form);


var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
var file = fileInput.files[0];
formData.append('our-file', file);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();   

  xhr.upload.addEventListener('loadstart', onloadstartHandler, false);
  xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', onprogressHandler, false);
  xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', onloadHandler, false);
  xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', onreadystatechangeHandler, false);   


  xhr.open('POST', 'http://www.server1.com/upload.php', true);  

  xhr.send(formData);
```

---

The issue is if I want to post to an alternate domain (ie: www.server2.com/upload.php) it doesn't work.  It only works if I post to the same domain that the script is residing on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security restriction imposed by design, to prevent cross-site scripting attacks. You can do it by [using a proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html) or with [this solution](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2010/03/12/making-cross-domain-javascript-requests-using-xmlhttprequest-or-xdomainrequest.html) if you can change the HTTP headers sent by the server.

Comment: Thanks that worked however i'm still having an issue with IE10 - any special treatment for IE10 specifically?  It seems that others are having the same issue and i'm not able to find an IE10 specific solution anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really know any IE 10 specifics, as I rarely target the IE browsers. Also, please upvote me if my response was helpful.